# Loop through json with non-numeric keys dynamically

Tags: java, android, json

I have this json:

```
{"produtos": {
    "Su\u00edte Master": {
        "variacao": {
            "variationcustom1bla": {
                "descricao": "2\u00aa a 6\u00aa - 1h",
                "preco": "60.00",
                "percentual": "0.00"
            },
            "variationcusstom1bla": {
                "descricao": "2\u00aa a 6\u00aa - 2h",
                "preco": "70.00",
                "percentual": "0.00"
            },

        }
    },
    "Suitetematica": {
        "variacao": {
            "variation bla2 custom bla2": {
                "descricao": "3\u00aa at\u00e9 5\u00aa as 18h - 2h",
                "preco": "99.00",
                "percentual": "20.00"
            },
            "Pernoites": {
                "descricao": "Pernoites",
                "preco": "149.00",
                "percentual": "5.00"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
try {
    JSONObject produtos = new JSONObject(json);
    JSONArray produtosArr = produtos.getJSONArray("produtos");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // JSON error
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How can I go through this json using JSONObject()? It is returning this error:

at produtos of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
     ;

Comment: Show us how are you getting it

Comment: I edited my answer, look kindly. @MartinDeSimone

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject produtos= new JSONObject(json);
JSONObject object = produtos.optJSONObject("produtos");
```

Answer (score -1):

You must need to use JSONObject to parse the Json because this json has no Array element .So if you are trying to parse this json using JSONArray, it is showing the error message **org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray**

You can view the code :

```
    String jsonString  = "{\"produtos\":{\"Suíte Master\":{\"variacao\":{\"variationcustom1bla\":{\"descricao\":\"2ª a 6ª - 1h\",\"preco\":\"60.00\",\"percentual\":\"0.00\"},\"variationcusstom1bla\":{\"descricao\":\"2ª a 6ª - 2h\",\"preco\":\"70.00\",\"percentual\":\"0.00\"},\"variationssscustom1bla\":{\"descricao\":\"2ª a 6ª - 3h\",\"preco\":\"80.00\",\"percentual\":\"0.00\"},\"variatissssoncustom1bla\":{\"descricao\":\"Pernoite: de 21h até as 14h\",\"preco\":\"130.00\",\"percentual\":\"0.00\"}}},\"Suitetematica\":{\"variacao\":{\"variation bla2 custom bla2\":{\"descricao\":\"3ª até 5ª as 18h - 2h\",\"preco\":\"99.00\",\"percentual\":\"20.00\"},\"Pernoites\":{\"descricao\":\"Pernoites\",\"preco\":\"149.00\",\"percentual\":\"5.00\"}}}}}";
    try {
        JSONObject rootJObj  =  new JSONObject(jsonString) ;

        JSONObject jProdutos = rootJObj.getJSONObject("produtos") ;
        JSONObject suOBj1  = jProdutos.getJSONObject("Suíte Master");

        JSONObject variacaoJObj =  suOBj1.getJSONObject("variacao");
        JSONObject  varJObj1  =  variacaoJObj.getJSONObject("variationcustom1bla");
        String descricao1 =  varJObj1.getString("descricao");
        String preco1 =  varJObj1.getString("preco");
        String percentual1 =  varJObj1.getString("percentual");
        JSONObject  varJObj2  =  variacaoJObj.getJSONObject("variationcustom1bla");
        String descricao2 =  varJObj2.getString("descricao");
        String preco2 =  varJObj2.getString("preco");
        String percentua2 =  varJObj2.getString("percentual");
        JSONObject  varJObj3  =  variacaoJObj.getJSONObject("variationcustom1bla");
        String descricao3 =  varJObj3.getString("descricao");
        String preco3 =  varJObj3.getString("preco");
        String percentual3 =  varJObj3.getString("percentual");

        JSONObject  varJObj4  =  variacaoJObj.getJSONObject("variationcustom1bla");
        String descricao4 =  varJObj4.getString("descricao");
        String preco4 =  varJObj4.getString("preco");
        String percentual4 =  varJObj4.getString("percentual");
        JSONObject suOBj2  = jProdutos.getJSONObject("Suitetematica");
        JSONObject vaJsonObject = suOBj2.getJSONObject("variacao");
        JSONObject varBla2 = vaJsonObject.getJSONObject("variation bla2 custom bla2");
        String descricao5 =  varBla2.getString("descricao");
        String preco5 =  varBla2.getString("preco");
        String percentua5 =  varBla2.getString("percentual");
        JSONObject Pernoites = vaJsonObject.getJSONObject("Pernoites");
        String descricao6 =  Pernoites.getString("descricao");
        String preco6 =  Pernoites.getString("preco");
        String percentua6 =  Pernoites.getString("percentual");

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

May be this will be helpful to understand properly.

Comment: This is not very efficient

Comment: @MartinDeSimone How the better way for i leave this json more easier to java manipulate, because i can change it

Comment: Yes right , this is look like hardcoded. He must create json in good manner.If this is the json , you must need to do this way.If you have any other way , please tell me.